# how to put index data in div tag when using foreach and iterates back to the top codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to put index data when using foreach if there are 5 data and iterates back to the top

> how

```
foreach {

 div image 1 (this key 0 in foreach)
 div image 2 (this key 1 in foreach)
 div image 3 (this key 2 in foreach)
 div image 4 (this key 3 in foreach)
 div image 5 (this key 5 in foreach)

 and back to div image 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Follwing may help you.

```
<?
foreach($data as $item){
?>
<div>
<img src="image-<?=$item['index']?>.png" />
</div>
<?
}
?>
<div>
<img src="image-<?=$data[0]['index']?>.png" />
</div>
```

To got to top, You can simple refer to index zero like `$data[0]['index']`